# Python difference between statement and function

Tags: python, performance

I am currently using python to work with tons of data, and I got a bit curious...
Since it's a lot of data, code speed **really** matters, so is there a difference between a few statements and a function that do so? is there a difference between

```
def my_function(var1):
    var2 = var1 + 1
    var3 = var1 - 1
    var4 = str(var1)
    print(var2, var3, var4)


for i in range(100000):
    my_function(i)
```

and

```
for i in range(100000):
    var1 = i
    var2 = var1 + 1
    var3 = var1 - 1
    var4 = str(var1)
    print(var2, var3, var4)
```

when talking about how fast the code is?

Comment: Might have a small difference but don't think you call *"optimizing"* your code to remove the function. If you are doing math operations with lots of code, definetly shouldn't use a for loop, but rather use a library such as `numpy`

Comment: Why don't you [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)?

Comment: In your example, you will not see any measurable performance difference. I can tell you that the majority of the time will be in the `print` function.

Comment: Write your code first, then profile it before you do any optimisation. There is likely to be a lot of other places you can optimise before removing a function call.

Comment: I ain't really doing math operations, and I won't use the function out of the loop, this is just an easier way to represent my current code, yes, I have a `for` loop, the "print" function is just to show that it actually **does** something, and it's a statement, rather than an expressions. My code is not complete yet, but I think optimizing it would make the remaining work a LOT faster. any changes I make I wait ~20 seconds

Answer (score 1):

It most likely won't have any measurable effect on your code, unless you're doing pretty much nothing inside the function.

To illustrate:

```
In [1]: def spam(eggs):
   ...:     pass
   ...:
   ...:

In [2]: def a():
   ...:     for i in range(1000000):
   ...:         spam(i)
   ...:

In [3]: def b():
   ...:     for i in range(1000000):
   ...:         pass
   ...:

In [4]: %timeit a()
104 ms ± 3.53 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit b()
25.9 ms ± 871 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If, however, the code is actually doing something you won't really notice the difference anymore:

```
In [1]: def spam(eggs):
   ...:     return sum(x for x in range(eggs))
   ...:
   ...:

In [2]: def a():
   ...:     total = 0
   ...:     for i in range(1000):
   ...:         total += spam(i)
   ...:

In [3]: def b():
   ...:     total = 0
   ...:     for i in range(1000):
   ...:         total += sum(x for x in range(i))
   ...:

In [4]: %timeit a()
31 ms ± 1.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit b()
31.8 ms ± 1.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Also: Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- DonaldKnuth

Answer (score 0):

When it's being interpreted there's a small difference, but it depends on the function size, how many times it's being called, what it's doing, etc.

For compiled Python code, the compiler is generally smart enough to "unwrap" functions into their component pieces for optimization.